# review: remove duplicate from an array

Tags: arrays, c, loops, duplicates, integer

I have come up with a code to remove duplicate from an array, and wanted it to have reviewed for mistakes (for instance, is it ok to have sizeof for array index) ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
        int a[] = {1,2,4,4,5,6,2,7, INT32_MAX};
        int flag[sizeof(a)] = {0}, i=0,j=0; 

        while (a[i] != INT32_MAX ) {
                 if(a[i] != a[i+1])
                        a[j++] = a[i];
#if 0
                if(0 == flag[a[i]]) {
                        flag[a[i]] = 1;
                        a[j++] = a[i];
                }
#endif
        i++;
        }

        for (i =0;i<j;i++)
                printf("%d\n", a[i]);
};
```

Comment: Hint: you don't need the `flags` array.

Comment: `sizeof(a)`  is wrong. Think about what happens if `a` contains a big number, e.g 2000. You would address `flag[2000]` at some point.... Rewrite your code without the `flag` array, you don't need it.

Comment: @Jabberwocky, did try other version without flag array but it seems to only work with sorted array.

Comment: Requests for code reviews should be posted to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hint: you basically need 3 nested loops: one loop scans the array from 0 to the end, the next inner loop  searches for duplicates of the current number, and the most inner loop shifts the remaining numbers. A piece of paper and a pencil are most helpful here.

Comment: Note: `INT32_MAX` is not the max value for a `int`; replace it with `INT_MAX`.

Comment: I think you should clarify what you mean. You cannot really "remove" something from an array in C. They have fixed size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This initialization of the array

```
int a[] = {1,2,4,4,5,6,2,7, INT32_MAX};
```

does not make a sense. In general the type `int` can be not the same as the type `int32_t`. So it is unclear why this value is present in the initialization list and why the code depends on this value.

To remove duplicate elements in an integer array neither sentinel value is required.

Moreover in your code the value INT32_MAX will not present in the result sub-array due to the condition in the while loop

```
while (a[i] != INT32_MAX ) {
```

and in general a sentinel value can be absent in a character array.

Also in general `a[i]` can be greater than `sizeof( a )`. So this if statement

```
if(0 == flag[a[i]])
```

does not make a sense and can invoke undefined behavior.

The code can look the following way

```
int a[] = {1,2,4,4,5,6,2,7 };
const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

size_t n = 0;

for ( size_t i = 0; i != N; i++ )
{
    size_t j = 0;

    while ( j != n && a[j] != a[i] ) j++;

    if ( j == n ) a[n++] = a[i];
}

for ( size_t i = 0; i != n; i++ )
{
    printf( "%d ", a[i] );
}
putchar( '\n' );
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    int a[] = {1,2,4,4,5,6,2,7 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    size_t n = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i != N; i++ )
    {
        size_t j = 0;

        while ( j != n && a[j] != a[i] ) j++;

        if ( j == n ) a[n++] = a[i];
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i != n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );    

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 4 5 6 7
```

If you want to use a sentinel value when just write the for loop like

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i != N && a[i] != SentinelValue; i++ )
```

where `SentinelValue` is some value.

and then after the loop you should write

```
a[n++] = SentinelValue;
```

Comment: I think `INT32_MAX` is the sentinel value

Comment: @Jabberwocky It does not make a sense. The task does not require a sentinel value.

Comment: You are right, a sentinal value is not needed here, but look at the OP's code: he is obviously using `INT32_MAX` as a sentinel value: `while (a[i] != INT32_MAX )`

Comment: @Jabberwocky This is his mistake. A sentinel value is not required for such a task.

Comment: Forget my second comment, I delete it

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Your solution is correct, and you are right that a sentinel value is not required for such a task, but OP seems to want to use it (as in the original OP's code). A sentinel value, for instance, would avoid the use of a second variable to keep track of the array's size, so it has some benefits.